# ANTLR (ANTLR3) 2 cases or anything else pattern

Tags: c++, parsing, antlr, antlr3

I need C++ code generation that's why I'm using ANTLR3.
I would like parse:
Identifier ( TOKEN_A ( LEX_A | LEX_B | ANYTHING ) TOK_B )
I implement it like that:

```
enum_default_value_coma
:
EQUAL
(   valI0=SIGNED_INTEGER    { m_oCurrentEnumValue.AddDefaultValue( static_cast< Int64 >( atoll( $valI0.text.c_str() ) ) ); }
|   valU0=UNSIGNED_INTEGER  { m_oCurrentEnumValue.AddDefaultValue( static_cast< UInt64 >( atoll( $valU0.text.c_str() ) ) ); }
|   valS0=XXXXXX            { m_oCurrentEnumValue.AddDefaultValue( $valS0.text ); }
)?
COMA { m_oCurrentEnum.AddValue( m_oCurrentEnumValue ); }
;
```

I don't know how can I detect the "anything else", XXXXXX.
Have we a "Else" pattern?

Thanks

Comment: Hello,I know how to can "anything" with "." on ANTL but my question is about the "else pattern":

Comment: What I tried:
enum_member
 : ID  { m_oCurrentEnumValue.SetName( $ID.text ); }
 ( EQUAL
  ( SIGNED_INTEGER_VALUE { m_oCurrentEnumValue.AddDefaultValue( static_cast< Int64 >( atoi( $SIGNED_INTEGER_VALUE.text.c_str() ) ) ); }
  | UNSIGNED_INTEGER_VALUE { m_oCurrentEnumValue.AddDefaultValue( static_cast< UInt64 >( atoi( $UNSIGNED_INTEGER_VALUE.text.c_str() ) ) ); }
  | SOMETHING  { m_oCurrentEnumValue.AddDefaultValue( $SOMETHING.text ); }
  )
 )? { m_oCurrentEnum.AddValue( m_oCurrentEnumValue ); }
 ;*
But SOMETHING contain more prior lexer exemple.

Comment: To fix that I do a more complexe parser to describe strictly my "SOMETHING".